# Given a series of users and movies they watched in a data frame, how can I group all the movies the user watched?

Tags: r, dataframe, recommendation-engine

So, I have a data frame, with userid and movieid, where each line represent a user and a movie he watched. Something like:

```r
userid    movieid
882359    81
882359    926
882359    1349
881235    27
```

And what I want is

```r
userid     movieid
882359     c(81,926,1349)
881235     c(27)
```

How can I accomplish this? The data base is quite large (8 million rows) and in the end I would like to convert it to a binaryRatingMatrix. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .(films = paste(movieid, collapse = ",")), by = "userid"]

   userid       films
1: 882359 81,926,1349
2: 881235          27
```

If you prefer storing into a `list` rather than a character vector:

```r
df[, .(films = list(movieid)), by = "userid"]
   userid          films
1: 882359   81, 926,1349
2: 881235             27
```

(seemingly the same output but the types are not the same)

Comment: Cool ! I updated the answer if you prefer storing lists than character vectors. Since you look happy with the solution, would you mind accepting it ([see here for guidelines if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Answer (score 0):

An option with `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(films = movieid) ~ userid, df, FUN = I)
```